# import class success but when try to use it it gives error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

in my jsp page i imported class and it works file in my pc on tomcat 7 but when i upload it to my server it give compilation error for jsp file my code for

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page import="com.*" %>
<%@ page import="DIO.*" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

and place where i am getting error is

```
<td class="value"><%= com.PageCounter.getIntTodaysCount() %></td>
```

my class PageCounter is inside com package and it works file on my local host pc 
errror when uploading to server

and error is

```
An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PageCounter cannot be resolved
29: <table cellspacing="0" class="info_table"   style="height: 175px" >
30: <tbody>
31:   <tr>
32:     <td class="value"><%= PageCounter.getIntTodaysCount() %></td>
33:     <td class="full">Visits Today</td>
34:   </tr>
```

doe it will due to change in version of tomcat

any suggetion will be great help

error is

```
An error occurred at line: 51 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
DIO cannot be resolved to a type

48: <div class="portlet-header">
49: <h4>Upcoming Events</h4>
50: </div> <!-- .portlet-header -->
51: <% DIO sharedDataBase = (DIO)application.getAttribute("sharedDataBase");
52: String[][] eventData=sharedDataBase.getData("select eventName,eventDescription,eventDate from listOfEvents order by eventDate desc", 10);%>
53: <div class="portlet-content">
54: <marquee direction="up" onmouseover="stop()" style="height: 200px" onmouseout="start()" scrollamount="2"


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

page counter class

```
package com;

import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import DIO.DIO;

public class PageCounter {
    private static int count;
    private static int todaysCount;
    private static Date previousDate=new Date();

    public static int getIntTodaysCount(){
        Date date = new Date();
        if (previousDate.before(date)) {
            ++todaysCount;
        }else{
            previousDate=date;
            todaysCount=1;
        }
        return todaysCount;
    }

    public static int getIntCount(DIO sharedDataBase){
        count++;
        try {
            sharedDataBase.updateData("update pageCount set pageCount="+count+" where pageCountId=1");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;

    }

}
```

Comment: can you append the error message?

Comment: import statements are working correctly even this file is running correctly on my pc

Comment: int the error message on line 32 the com. is missing  - can you check the jsp on your server that it actually contains the "com."?

Comment: yes my package contains WEB_INF/classes/com/* all classes and i tried with fully qualified name com.PageCounter And with import statement

Comment: also can you show us PageCounter class

Comment: That should be `WEB-INF`. Can you confirm you have a dash (hyphen) and not a skid (underscore) in the path?

Comment: i solved that issue it was related to version i used firs was 1.7.45 and server version was 1.7.17 that was issue thanks for help